# Why does Windows take so much time to connect to a wifi network?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking

My Windows 7 laptop takes 1-2 minutes to connect to a wifi network. As a college student, my laptop goes in and out of sleep multiple times throughout the day. Having to wait a few minutes for internet each time I open it is getting annoying.

This happens when connected whether or not the power cable is plugged in.

Comment: @up yep, don't fix the problem, just throw this away and give a bunch ones to yourself free! Damn, thats good...

Comment: More information is required.  Are you allowing Windows to manage your wireless connection or using third-party software to do it?

Comment: Switch off the wireless router and switch it on.

Comment: If you connect to a network using an Ethernet cable, are you able to connect to a network right away? If not, you're not experiencing a Wi-Fi issue at all.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** I'm still experiencing the same problem with this service enabled and running

Found the answer [here](http://forums.techguy.org/print/923376-wireless-takes-long-time-connect.html)

> This is for XP/Vista,but hopefully ,7 will be similar.
>
> You would be looking for wlan/or wzc AND some d-link wireless manager manager associated with the wireless card running simultaneously.
>
> Check your Services are Started on all PCs:
> •  COM+ Event System (for WZC issues)
> •  Computer Browser
> •  DHCP Client
> •  DNS Client
> •  Network Connections
> •  Network Location Awareness
> •  Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
> •  Server
> •  TCP/IP Netbios helper
> •  Wireless Zero Configuration (XP wireless configurations) 
> •  WLAN AutoConfig (Vista wireless configurations) This would be the Vista default wireless manager,for example.
> •  Workstation
>
> Note: You can check the services in Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Services.
>
> All of these services should be started, and their startup type should be automatic (or perhaps manual).
>
> If a service is not running, open it's properties and check the dependencies. Check each of the dependencies and see which one is preventing the service from running. Checking the event log is also a good idea here, there may be clues to what is failing.

For me, it was simply a matter of starting the Computer Browser service and setting it to start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your network card drivers. But don't through Windows Update but looking for a suitable driver on you laptop manufacturer's website.

Does this happen when connecting to only one wifi network or does it connect with a lag to every wifi network you try to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume for the rest of the answer that you only have a 2.4ghz card--as is common in Windows devices (and everything else really). If you do a search for Device Manager in the Start Menu you will be able to look through the list of devices and find your network adapter. Clicking this will bring up a General page and from there go to the Advanced tab. There are your settings. If there is no mention of 5ghz in the settings you don't have a capable adapter.

Since you are at college there is a good chance that this is an WPA Enterprise network (do you enter your uni log in information to connect?) and there are a few caveats. These networks broadcast both on 2.4ghz and 5ghz ranges and provide support for AGN networking. N has the capacity to support 5ghz (is able, doesn't always). I would shut off B if you can in your WiFi driver settings. This might help.

The problem here is that most devices only support 2.4ghz which means that network is very crowded. Schools look to setup connection rules that will encourage 5ghz devices to connect to that range *first*. This means that most 2.4ghz devices will always connect slower. The problem with this method is that some devices' connection attempts timeout before they can actually connect to the network. You could be in this group. Your computer would then reload the network and start all over.

Do everything else suggested and then look on Amazon for a 5ghz USB network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off power saver on the nic.

For Windows 7 do the following:

- Click on the Windows Start button
- In the Search window type "network and sharing center"
- Press enter
- In the left pane of the NetWork and Sharing Center select "Change adapter settings"
- Right-Click your wireless device and select "Properties"
- Click "Configure"
- Select the "Power Mangement" tab
- Deselect "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
- Click OK

Now the wireless nic will remain powered even when the system sleeps.
Keep in mind that this will mean reduced battery life.

If it is still an issue then you can always turn all Power Savers off for the laptop by typing in the Windows-Start-Search "Power Options", then select "Change when the computer sleeps", then for "Put the computer to sleep" chose "NEVER" for "On Battery" and "Plugged In". 
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem then I switched off ip v6 in wifi properties and problem solved...

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Usually turning off power saver on the your card (as mentioned above by John) will do the trick:

For Windows 7 do the following:

Click on the Windows Start button
In the Search window type "network and sharing center"
Press enter
In the left pane of the NetWork and Sharing Center select "Change adapter settings"
Right-Click your wireless device and select "Properties"
Click "Configure"
Select the "Power Mangement" tab
Deselect "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
Click OK

But also do this:
Click on the Windows Start button
In the Search window type "network and sharing center"
Press enter
In the left pane of the NetWork and Sharing Center select "Change adapter settings"
Right-Click your wireless device and select "Properties"
Find check box that says Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6) and uncheck it. (make sure Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) IS STILL checked)
Click OK

Still slow? Do this:
(but ONLY if your wifi is the only connection you use, as this may not connect to other wifi's properly after this step)

With your wifi actually connected, open up a command prompt by typing cmd in the search bar of your start menu. (a window will show up waiting for you to type commands in)
Type in:

ipconfig /all

All of you Network cards will be listed. Find the one for your wireless card and write down the IP it was assigned, subnet mask, default gateway, and the DNS server addresses. Usually 2 or 3 DNS servers:

EXAMPLE (it should look similar to this):
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection

Write down the IP addresses are the numbers with periods that look similar to this:

- IPv4 Address.....: 192.168.1.24
- Subnet Mask......: 255.255.255.0
- Default Gateway..: 192.168.1.1
- DHCP Server......: 192.168.1.1
- DNS Servers......: 192.168.1.1

Open your network and sharing center. 
Click on Change Adapter Settings. 
Right click on your wireless adapter, and again go down to properties. 
Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and click on properties.

Click the radio buttons to manually enter the addresses, and enter the numbers you wrote down. Select Ok, and then Ok again, and it should automatically disconnect then reconnect. 
Restart Computer and put the computer to sleep, then wake it up and see if it made any difference.

To undo this step and set everything back to automatic connection so you can connect to other wifi networks just go back into Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) properties and click the radio buttons back to Obtain IP Address Automatically, as well as Obtain DNS Server Address Automatically.
Click OK, and then OK again.
Restart Computer.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and fixed it by uninstalling and reinstalling the driver. (requires Admin)

I didn't want to turn off power-saver mode, as the others are suggesting. That means you don't have to reconnect because it never disconnects, but drains the battery by staying connected, and I like to leave my computer in sleep for long periods of time.

1. Open Network and Sharing Center (can be found from the network status icon in the task bar, or from the Control Panel, or by searching the start menu)
2. Click "Manage Adapter Settings" in the side bar.
3. Right click on the troublesome adapter, and select "Properties". (For me, the adapter was labeled Wireless Network Connection.)
4. Click on "Configure..."
5. In the Driver tab, click "Uninstall". Then reboot your computer.

> NOTE: This will disconnect you from the internet. When you reboot, the
>   driver will reinstall itself, so make sure you don't check the 'remove
>   driver from this computer' box.
>
> Some people posting on other forums had luck simply rolling back the driver, or updating to the newest version. These options didn't work for me, but you might have better luck. They can be accessed from the same configuration menu.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything else, I found the (1 minute or so) delay was due to delay in reaching the DNS. Changed the DNS to one offered by by ISP, problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

This Worked for me on Windows 10, Lenovo G50 Laptop

Check your Services are Started on all PCs: • COM+ Event System (for WZC issues)

Computer Browser

DHCP Client

DNS Client

Network Connections

Network Location Awareness

Remote Procedure Call (RPC)

Server

TCP/IP Netbios helper

Wireless Zero Configuration (XP wireless configurations)

WLAN AutoConfig (Vista wireless configurations) This would be the Vista default

wireless manager,for example.

Workstation